Why does the following code does not leak memory
I was reading retain cycle and tried the following code which should in theory leak memory but when I use Instruments, it does not show any memory leaks
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var button = {
        let _button = UIButton()
        _button.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        _button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        return _button
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc private func actionButton() {
        
        let secondVC = ViewController2()
        
        present(secondVC, animated: true)
    }

}

class MyView: UIView {
    
    let viewContoller: ViewController2
    
    init(from vc: ViewController2) {
        viewContoller = vc
        
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    
    var myView: MyView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        myView = MyView(from: self)
    }
    
}


There's a button on ViewController which upon tapping opens a new view controller ViewController2 which initialises a UIView and when I dismiss that view controller(ViewController2), it should create a retain cycle (since the view also holds ViewController2 object). Where exactly am I going wrong?
Edit 1: I tried the deinit inside the ViewController2 and it worked as expected. However, the confusion started when I tried to profile the same code on Instruments app and it showed "No Leaks", green ticks all the way

You reference Instruments’ “Leaks” tool. That is for finding low-level allocations for which you no longer have any reference, but subsequently failed to deallocate. It is not for, nor will it identify, “strong reference cycles” (previously known as “retain cycles”). FWIW, true “leaks” are exceedingly unusual in Swift, unless using low-level memory techniques. Debug memory graph is the “go to” technique for identifying strong reference cycles.

@Rob I think what's going on is a little more interesting than that. The debug memory graph, as my answer shows, does not demarcate the cycle qua cycle either, as one would expect. But it does demarcate the cycle, and the Leaks instrument does register the leak, if we deliberately remove the notification center's reference to the second view controller, as I have now explained in a revision to my answer.

My point (referenced in your “bonus discussion”) is simply that Instruments’ “Leaks” is the wrong tool to reliably identify strong reference cycles (“abandoned” memory). “Abandoned” memory is different than a “leak”. For strong reference cycles, the “debug memory graph” (DMG) tool is the easiest way to go. Now, yes, the DMG won’t always show a nice circular graph nor the warning triangle (e.g., esp. when an OS object is involved in the cycle), but you will see the unreleased objects in the panel on the left, and with malloc stack feature, you can identify where the strong references are.

You have successfully created a retain cycle. Your only problem is how to detect it. To detect the retain cycle, add these lines to MyView and ViewController2, respectively:
deinit {
    print("farewell from MyView")
}

deinit {
    print("farewell from ViewController2")
}

Now run your app, tap the button, and dismiss (by dragging) the presented view controller. Nothing prints to the console. Thus we know that neither ViewController2 nor MyView are being deallocated. That's the leak.

It will also help to make a contrasting situation so that you can see that the "farewell" messages would print if there were not a retain cycle. To make it, change MyView like this:
let viewContoller: ViewController2?

init(from vc: ViewController2?) {
    viewContoller = vc

    super.init(frame: .zero)
}

Now change
    myView = MyView(from: self)

to
    myView = MyView(from: nil)

Run the app, tap the button, and dismiss (by dragging) the presented view controller. The deinit messages print! Thus we have created a red-green test that demonstrates the retain cycle. You can change the code back to
    myView = MyView(from: self)

and confirm that the deinit message do not print. Have fun playing with your brand new retain cycle demonstration app!

It is also possible to detect the cycle using the Memory Graph feature. Note the infinite chain (I have stopped opening pointees after the first repetition):


Bonus discussion:
Why doesn't the Leaks instrument display the leak? Because it is not, of itself, a leak. It is a retain cycle. But there is no leak, because there is another object that still has a reference to the ViewController2 instrument: the notification center.
To see this, add this code to your ViewController2 viewDidLoad method:
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

Now profile the app under the Leaks instrument. In my test, this is what I now see:

Without that extra reference from the notification center, this retain cycle is now also a leak: the ViewController2 and the MyView are retaining one another, and there are no other references to them.
Moreover, the memory graph display now calls out the retain cycle explicitly:

Okay, so now you may ask: why was the notification center keeping a reference to the view controller? I have no real idea, but I guess it's a feature of the UIKit framework. There are some notifications that can come to a view controller without the view controller having to register explicitly to receive them, and I suppose that this is how that feature is configured (when a view controller enters the view controller hierarchy).

Thanks for the reply. I tried with deinit to start with and it was working as expected. Although,  the confusion started when I tried the "Leaks" tool of the Instrument app and it showed "No leaks" for the code. Any idea why that might be the case?

That seems to me like a different question, so you are now shifting your ground. You didn't mention deinit in your original question; you asked whether you were doing something wrong in your attempt to create a retain cycle, and I believe I answered that. If you think there's a problem with the Instruments Leaks instrument, you can ask about that separately and/or file a bug report with Apple.

@user121095 Okay, I've figured out how to make Instruments display the leak! I'll add my explanation to the answer.

FWIW, in Transitioning to ARC Release Notes, Apple introduced “strong reference cycle” in lieu of “retain cycle”. The Swift Language: Automatic Reference Counting also uses the term “strong reference cycle”, not “retain cycle”. The term “retain cycle” was used back when we used to manually retain/release objects.

You are in fact creating a retain cycle, you can either check the debug memory graph after dismissing ViewController2 and the instance will be there:

Or you can implement the deinit method and log something:
deinit { print("Instance removed from memory") }

In any case, with the code you provided the instance will be showing in the memory graph and the deinit method won't be called in either the view nor the controller 2.
In order to break the cycle you would need a reference to be weak (or unowned) like so:
weak var viewContoller: ViewController2?


Thanks for the reply. I tried with deinit to start with and it was working as expected. Although,  the confusion started when I tried the "Leaks" tool of the Instrument app and it showed "No leaks" for the code. Any idea why that might be the case?
